# What type of hash is this MD4(MD4(($pass)).(strtolower($username)))

Tags: passwords, hash

Can I decrypt this hash?

Domain Cached Credentials:
`MD4(MD4(($pass)).(strtolower($username)))`

Comment: uh - it looks like an MD4 hash ... What is your question? What type is it, or how to "decrypt" the hash?

Comment: Please note that no one can "decrypt" a hash. They are meant to be one-way only.

Comment: Let me guess, you found that in `hash-identifier`?

Comment: first i want to thank you to answer :) ,yes .. i found it in hash-identifier , and i don' t know if i can use the Hashcat to guess the hash please if you now a method which can guess this hash or if you know any information about this hash tell me please :)

Comment: Everything you need to know about that hash is in the code. I'm not sure what else you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes are *not* compression schemes.  The password you are looking for is not stored in the hash, though it is theoretically possible that somebody has a dictionary that maps it to its original content.

Given knowledge of the scheme,

```
MD4(MD4(($pass)).(strtolower($username)))
```

You can guess it.  MD4 is decently fast to calculate, so if you have `$username`, all that's left is `$pass`.

You can either build such a thing yourself, or use something like [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/), which I assume can be configured to attack this scheme.

As to what *type* of hash it is, you've mostly answered the question by naming how it is composed.  [MD4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD4) is a rather old yet fast digest algorithm.  This scheme uses that algorithm twice; first, it hashes the password and concatenates the hash with the lowercase form of the username, then it hashes that resulting string.

Sample implementation in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Digest::MD4 "md4_hex";

my $username = shift;
my $pass = shift;

print md4_hex( md4_hex($pass) . lc($username) ) . "\n";
```

Some outputs:

```
$ perl sample.pl user password
200677efff76ec27e716b319b611e217
$ perl sample.pl AzureDiamond hunter2
8ff17c78faf27083670a7423a90a964c
```

Sample (dumb) brute force password cracker:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Digest::MD4 "md4_hex";

my $username = shift;
my $pw_hash = shift;
my $i = 0;

sub hash_check {
  shift;
  if (md4_hex( md4_hex($_) . lc($username) ) eq $pw_hash) {
    print "\r$i\nPassword found: '$_'\n";
    exit;
  }
}

LINE: while() {
  chomp;

  my @variants = ($_);
  my $v = $_;
  $v =~ s/\W//g; # strip non-word chars
  push(@variants, $v) if ($_ ne $v);
  $v = lc($_); # all lowercase
  push(@variants, $v) if ($_ ne $v);
  $v =~ s/\W//g; # all lowercase AND strip non-word chars
  push(@variants, $v) if ($_ ne $v);
  $v = uc(substr($_,0,1)).substr($_,1); # uppercase 1st char
  push(@variants, $v) if ($_ ne $v);
  $v =~ s/\W//g; # uppercase 1st char AND strip non-word chars
  push(@variants, $v) if ($_ ne $v);

  for my $pw (@variants) {
    # try followed by nothing or 1-2 digits
    for my $j ("", 0..99, qw/00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09/) {
      $i++;
      print "\r$i" if $i % 111 == 0; # only print every 111 (this is FAST)
      $_ = $pw . $j;
      last LINE if hash_check($_);
    }
  }
}
print "\r$i\n";
```

Some outputs:

```
$ echo password |perl sample.pl user 200677efff76ec27e716b319b611e217
1
Password found: 'password'
$ perl /tmp/sample.pl user a3c705c458e12e2f9982ae2682b437f8 american-english
26955905
Password found: 'password07'
$ perl sample.pl admin 4ef6c6a21c0172c8cd322dd8f78ba6c1 american-english-huge
126764776
$
```

My laptop (which ran this at 650k pw/sec) didn't find your password given these simple iterations (dictionary word with some guesses about case, 0-2 digits following it).  /usr/share/dict/american-english-huge has 341,472 words and comes from the Debian package wamerican-huge version 7.1-1.

Comment: this is the hash 4ef6c6a21c0172c8cd322dd8f78ba6c1 and this is the $username ; that is mean the follow : MD4(MD4(($pass)).(strtolower(admin))) the problem in password can i use John The Riper to find it

Comment: I keep meaning to try John the Ripper, but I haven't yet.  You can manually try this with a simple script (added above), but you'll have to invent all of the possible password schemes manually (it wasn't an obvious one).